# Картинка увеличивается и уменьшается

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Как сделать так чтобы картинка не увеличивалась и не уменьшалась когда прибавляешь проценты в браузере. Если увеличивать в браузере или уменьшать страницу чтобы изображение не менялось.

Answer (score 0):

Для ширины и высоты изображения используйте единицы измерения `vw` и `vh` соответственно.